# How to get socket structure using socket fd associated with it in user space?

Tags: c

I have socket fd, I want to get the socket to which this fd is bound to.
my code is

```
   create_socket(int nl_groups)
   {
    int s;
    struct sockaddr_nl nladdr;

    if((   s = socket    (AF_NETLINK,    SOCK_RAW,     NETLINK_GENERIC)) < 0)
    return s;

    memset (&nladdr, 0, sizeof nladdr);`enter code here`
    nladdr.nl_family = AF_NETLINK;
    nladdr.nl_pid = 0;
    nladdr.nl_groups = nl_groups;
    if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr*)&nladdr, sizeof(nladdr)) < 0) {
    close(s);
    return -1;
    }
    return s;
}
```

I saw in kernel space we can use struct `socket * sockfd_lookup  (int fd, int * err);`
this returns the socket object pointer,
But I want to know how can we get socket in user space.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: why would you want to do that, i mean what's the use case?

Comment: i want to pass this socket ptr to other function say nl_socket_add_membership(struct nl_sock *sk, int group), which expects socket ptr. Since i have socket fd i want to get socket to which it is associated with.

Comment: the fdopen() function does exactly what you want.